# insert into table from query in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `Ty` contains:

```
  a integer NOT NULL,
  b text,
  c text,
  d text,
  e text
```

I'm trying to do insrert statment as follows:

```
insert into Ty (b,c,d,e) values
                ('hello','world',select current_date,select name from users where userid=4)
```

But it doesn't work. It says:

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "select"

All guides I read says that I can do SQL statement in Insert as long as they return just one value. So why it doesn't work?

Comment: You need parentheses around the subqueries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
insert into Ty (b,c,d,e)
SELECT 'hello','world',current_date, name from users where userid=4
```

Answer (score 2):

```
insert into Ty (b,c,d,e) 
select 'hello','world',current_date,name from users 
where userid=4
```

Comment: The keyword values causes same error. @Paul answer works

Comment: I noticed extrac brace and already removed it. See my edited reply

Comment: Still won't work; the `values` keyword shouldn't be there

Answer (score 0):

a second way to do it is to add ( ) around the SELECT as shown in the next example:

```
test=# SELECT (SELECT 1);
 ?column? 
----------
        1
(1 row)
```